# create exception when python command generates a program.exe has stopped working type error

Tags: python-3.x, error-handling

I am facing a problem with a program i am developing in Python 3.6 under Windows 10.

One particular command generates an unknown error, windows throws a 'program.exe has stopped working' message and the program exits.

The command is a 3d-model loader that is part of another python package (Panda3D). The crash is always associated with this command (and more particularly with a specific dll of the loader) and a particular file that it tries to open.

Since i cannot locate and therefore solve the faults in the dll (probably there is a bug there) i would like to just pass the problematic file and continue to the next one. But since python exits and i do not know the error type, the typical try, except does not work.

So, i would like to know if there is a way to predict this type of behavior in my code and prevent the program from exiting.

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

The pop-up "Program.exe has stopped working." can be caused by a variety of things and therefor there is no "one size fits all" type solution. But if you're certain that your problem is cause by a specific line of code you can always try something along the lines of :

```
try:
    loader.loadModel("c/path/to/your/file")
except Exception as e:
    print(e.message, e.args)
    # your error-handling code here
```

Make sure the file path that you're giving to loadModel respects the following :

```
# WRONG:
loader.loadModel("c:\\Program Files\\My Game\\Models\\Model1.egg")

# RIGHT:
loader.loadModel("/c/Program Files/My Game/Models/Model1.egg")
```

Source : [pandas3d official documentation](https://docs.panda3d.org/1.10/python/programming/models-and-actors/loading-models)

Comment: nope. the' try except' will not work in this case. the loader command probably creates a memory leak and crashes python itself before going to Except. Also the paths are correct as the loader works just fine with all the other files.